# How to filter multiple condition in scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, filter

Do have a question in Scala.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()

val data = Seq(("James","Smith","USA","CA"),
  ("Michael","Rose","USA","NY"),
  ("Robert","Williams","USA","CA"),
  ("Maria","Jones","USA","FL")
  )

val columns = Seq("firstname","lastname","country","state")
import spark.implicits._
val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)

df.show(false)
```

| firstname | lastname | country | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Smith | USA | CA |
| Michael | Rose | USA | NY |
| Robert | Williams | USA | CA |
| Maria | Jones | USA | FL |

I would like to filter this something like this using state to filter with CA and FL only. any idea? What I'm looking for is something filter with Seq any possible? THanks

```
df.filter("state" === Seq("CA", "FL"))
```

| firstname | lastname | country | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Smith | USA | CA |
| Robert | Williams | USA | CA |
| Maria | Jones | USA | FL |

Comment: did you mean I could use this? df.filter($"state".isin(Seq("CA","NY"))) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

```
val selected = Seq("CA","NY")
df.filter($"state".isin(selected:_*)).show
```